# How to get table(scrappin) from a website

Tags: r, xml, rvest, xml2

please i want to get the table in this website into Rstudio :
"https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"

Am one month into learning R from scratch, this is what i have done:

```
library(XML)     
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url<-("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries")

covid<-readHTMLTable(url,which=1)

head(covid)
```

output error message

```
url<-("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries")
> covid<-readHTMLTable(url,which=1)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
In addition: Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: ''
```

please i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rvest` to get the data.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"

url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  replace(., . == '', NA)


#  Country,Other TotalCases NewCases TotalDeaths NewDeaths TotalRecovered ActiveCases Serious,Critical Tot Cases/1M pop
#1         China     80,894      +13       3,237        11         69,614       8,043            2,622               56
#2         Italy     31,506     <NA>       2,503        NA          2,941      26,062            2,060              521
#3          Iran     16,169     <NA>         988        NA          5,389       9,792             <NA>              193
#4         Spain     11,826     <NA>         533        NA          1,028      10,265              563              253
#5       Germany      9,414      +47          26        NA             71       9,317                2              112
#6      S. Korea      8,413      +93          84         3          1,540       6,789               59              164
#...
```

You can look into `readr::parse_number` to convert columns like `TotalCases`, `NewCases` into numeric format.